# Python in Linux: kill processes and sub-processes using the shell

Tags: python, linux, shell

**Q:** Given an ever-running python program that runs another python program as its child, how can one kill the processes using python shell [i.e. by fetching the processes pids and then execute `kill -9 <pid>`]?

**In more details:**

I have a script as follows:

```
from subprocess import *

while True:
    try:
        Popen("python ...").wait() # some scrpipt
    except:
        exit(1)
    try:
        Popen("python ...").wait() # some scrpipt
    except:
       exit(1)
```

Now when I want to kill this process and its children, I:

1. Run `"ps -ef | grep python"` to fetch the pids.
2. Run `kill -9 <pid>` to kill the processes.

**The result:** The processes keeps on running after being assign with new pids.

Is there a graceful way to enable the processes to gracefully exit when killed?

Comment: Where are you trying to kill it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a graceful way to enable the processes to gracefully exit when killed?

There isn't when you `kill -9`. Kill with SIGINT (`-2`) or SIGTERM (`-15`), and catch that using the signal module by registering a cleanup function that handles the graceful exit.

```
import sys
import signal

def cleanup_function(signal, frame):
    # clean up all resources
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cleanup_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code parent will wait for child's exit status. If parent is getting its exist status, then only it will proceed to next iteration.

Also, you can't catch `SIGKILL` (`SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` are uncaught-able signals )

`-9` means `SIGKILL`

You can implement `SIGNAL` handler incase of any other signals

```
import os
import time


def my_job():
    print 'I am {0}, son/daughter of {1}'.format(os.getpid(), os.getppid())
    time.sleep(50)
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            expired_child = os.wait() # if child is getting killed, will return a tuple containing its pid and exit status indication
            if expired_child:
                continue
        else:
            my_job()
```